# .IPA installation stuck on IPhone 5s( ios 10.0.2)

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

[image]

> I am trying to install .IPA File But it always got stuck. I had
>   confirmed UDID's of Device .I also had made a experiment in which i
>   created a blank application for ios But it also got stuck at
>   installing.I had tested same application on multiple device its working perfect on other IOS Devices e.g iphone4s ,ipad pro.

[image]

Here is my Config.xml

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.unitedway" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>VMS</name>
    <description>Volunteer Management System, Phone Application</description>
    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">PhoneGap Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~4.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~1.3.0" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Have you add device to provisioning profiles?

Comment: yeah i had added multiple device  to provisioning profiles . But only Iphone 5s  had that issue on remaining application work perfectly .  I had confirmed it UDID.

Comment: How do you archive the IPA file? Is it Ad-Hoc Provisioning profile? It seems you archive it using App Store provisioning profile.

Comment: BTW, have you pressed sync button after intalling?

Comment: No its not a Ad-hoc Provisioning Profile. And I had created Provisioning profile for development  and register multiple device against it.

Comment: yes While press syn button the application status remain installing.

Comment: Update _everything_ — update the phone to iOS 10.1, and update iTunes to 12.5.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> its not a Ad-hoc Provisioning Profile

That's the problem. The only apps that you can install onto your phone in this way are:

- An app you downloaded from the iTunes app store
- An app with an ad hoc provisioning profile that lists this device in its profile (this is a Deployment provisioning profile, and you have to have a developer membership in order to create one)

Comment: I am not using Ad-hoc Provisioning Profile , but I am using app store Provisioning Profile . Thanks for your time .

Comment: That's the problem. You cannot install from iTunes to a device using an App Store profile. You must use an Ad Hoc profile.